# Sort array with custom objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to sort an array, filled with objects from a class i wrote. The class i wrote contains an NSString itself, as the "name". So what i wanna do, is to sort the array, based on the name property the objects contain. I tried the simple:

```
[anArray sortedArrayUsingSelecter: CaseInsensitiveCompare];
```

But as you can guess, it sends the caseInsensitiveCompare message to the objects itself, and it won't respond to that one.

So i'm guessing i have to make my objects able to respond to the caseInsensitiveCompare? Not quite sure how to write such a method, so any pointers would be lovely.

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the method `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(MyClass *a, MyClass *b) {
    return [a.name caseInsensitiveCompare:b.name];
}];
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks chap. What exactly does this do? or i don't have to worry about it? it's taking a block as an argument, right?

Comment: Yes, it is using a block to sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can `sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr` ([NSArray reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)) to sort the array. For instance, if you want to sort by the `name` property, do the following (assuming your class is called `Person`):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [(Person *)a name];
    NSString *second = [(Person *)b name];
    return [first caseInsensitiveCompare:second];
}];
```